# pyspark access column of dataframe with a dot '.'

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

A pyspark dataframe containing dot (e.g. "id.orig_h") will not allow to `groupby` upon unless first renamed by `withColumnRenamed`. Is there a workaround? `` "`a.b`" `` doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to group?

Answer (score 14):

In my pyspark shell, the following snippets are working:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
myCol = col("`id.orig_h`")    
result = df.groupBy(myCol).agg(...)
```

and

```python
myCol = df["`id.orig_h`"]   
result = df.groupBy(myCol).agg(...)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel de Paula for your answer. Can you confirm that using ``groupby("`id.orig_h`")`` doesn't work?

Comment: @HananShteingart, for me the following code works: `df.groupBy("\`id.orig_h\`").agg(...)`

Comment: For me it doesn't. Can you please add more columns starting with id. ? I use pyspark 1.6

Comment: @HananShteingart how as your DataFrame created? How are you doing your groupBy operation? Can you show the result of `df.printSchema()`?